# Is it possible to add encryption capabilities to an already existing table?

Tags: postgresql, pgcrypto

I'm using pgcrypto module for PostgresSQL, and in the document it was indicated that this line:

```
  CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
```

should be executed before creating the table which stores encrypted data.

My question is, if the table has already been created without the above mentioned line being executed, can I modify the table later by running this line to give it the encryption ability?

My goal is to use *pgp_sym_encrypt()* for INSERT operations,  *pgp_sym_decrypt()* for SELECT operations and both functions for UPDATE operations. For now I can get prepare statement to work, but exec would fail, I guess because the CREATE EXTENSION line hasn't been run.

Comment: I guess it depends on how exactly you use this extension to "give [the table] the encryption ability"; can you add details?

Comment: Sorry for not providing the details, I'm aiming at using pgp_sym_encrypt() for INSERT operations and pgp_sym_decrypt() for SELECT operations. I'll update my question.

Comment: Don't use pgcrypto, encrypt and decrypt inside the application. You will have to rewrite the table.

Comment: pgcrypto doesn't offer transparent data encryption.  It just provides some tools you could use to implement it yourself (which I guess would then not qualify as transparent).  You need to create the extension before you can use it, but it doesn't matter when the table was created.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks for the answer!